# Angular & Typescript: Replace value if it matches a given string

Tags: angular, typescript, replace

I have an app that was written in angular and its purpose is to display metadata values of several items coming from a database. My goal is to rewrite the output of one metadatavalue, if it matches a given string (for example: If the metadatavalue matches "CC-BY-ND" it should output a link to the Creative Commons Website instead).

This is my Typescript-File ("metadata-values.component.ts"):

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MetadataValue } from '../../../core/shared/metadata.models';

/**
 * This component renders the configured 'values' into the ds-metadata-field-wrapper component.
 * It puts the given 'separator' between each two values.
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'ds-metadata-values',
  styleUrls: ['./metadata-values.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './metadata-values.component.html'
})
export class MetadataValuesComponent {

  /**
   * The metadata values to display
   */
  @Input() mdValues: MetadataValue[];
  /**
   * The seperator used to split the metadata values (can contain HTML)
   */
  @Input() separator: string;

  /**
   * The label for this iteration of metadata values
   */
  @Input() label: string;

}
```

And this is my html file ("metadata-values.component.html"):

```
<ds-metadata-field-wrapper [label]="label | translate">
    <span class="dont-break-out" *ngFor="let mdValue of mdValues; let last=last;">
        {{mdValue.value}}<span *ngIf="!last" [innerHTML]="separator"></span>
    </span>
</ds-metadata-field-wrapper>
```

So basically I want to check if `{{mdValue.value}}` matches for example "CC-ND-BY" and replace the output with something else. Unfortunately my understanding of Typescript is very limited, so I would very much appreciate some help with my problem. :-( Thanks in advance to anyone reading this!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` on your string to see if it returns a value greater than -1. -1 being the default return of `indexOf` if there is no match. You can then combine this with a custom pipe, which might be overkill, or just do a basic method inside of your component like so:

```
translateValue(value: string) {

   //negative case. 
   if(value.indexOf("whateveryouarelookingfor") == -1)
      return value;

   return "your changed value";
}
```

then in your HTML your `{{mdValue.value}}` turns into `{translateValue(mdValue.value)}}`

**Edit:** Documentation for `string.indexOf` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

---

**Edit 2:**

As mentioned by Hassan, a Pipe would be a preferred approach. The way to do it would be as follows:

- Create a pipe and make sure you decorate it as such
- Add this pipe in the module for which your component belongs to
- call this pipe in the html

Working stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-njqyal?file=src/app/pipe/translate.pipe.ts

So then after you make your pipe your html will look like so: `{{mdValue.value | yourPipeName}}`

Comment: Thanks so much for your time and answer! I am afraid, I am still a bit lost:  If I put the translateValue-method into the HTML-File , it crashes. Could you specify on where and how this could be implemented? Since it is an html file I tried to enclose the code with <script> tags but unfortunatley that didnt work. Could you point out what I am missing here? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tony7654 put that method inside of the component class itself, not inside the HTML, so inside of your MetadataValuesComponent

Answer (score 0):

You can directly check for the *string match* in your HTML template. For example

```html
<ds-metadata-field-wrapper [label]="label | translate">
    <span class="dont-break-out" *ngFor="let mdValue of mdValues; let last=last;">
        {{ mdValue.value === 'CC-ND-BY' ? 'Value Matches String': mdValue.value }}
    <span *ngIf="!last" [innerHTML]="separator"></span>
    </span>
</ds-metadata-field-wrapper>
```

This is a very simple example considering you only want to match with a single string. I hope this can give you the guide to building more complex logic

Also, try to avoid calling a function directly in your HTML template. Performance wise it will run multiple times on every change detection i.e. in the answer given *translateValue()* will work but it's not the best approach.

The better approach would be to create a PIPE and use it or directly add your logic in the HTML template like I did in the example above.

Comment: Certainly cleaner, I do like your pipe option. I suggested the method approach since it is easier and ensures he also gets the compiler to help him. HTML can be tricky and it is polluting a little bit

Comment: Yep, You are correct. Not saying a method approach is a no-go place, it's a good approach to have a clean HTML. Just advising the OP to use it where necessary, unlike me who got to know about the performance impact of this approach very late into the Angular Project. For simple logics, I think adding directly is a good approach. For complex logics, we can embrace the trade-offs of the method approach in templates. :)

Comment: True, I do need to get out of the method mindset at times. Old habits die hard as a C# developer